# NavigationView SwiftUI shows split view in iPad

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview

With  `NavigationView` being the root of `UIHostingController` , the below code shows split view for iPad.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello")
                .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code it shows split view on iPad. How can I still use the `NavigationView` and get rid of split view for iPad , as I am looking to have a List and on tap of which it should push another view?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use stack navigation view style explicitly (by default it is platform-dependent)

```
NavigationView {
   Text("Hello")
       .navigationBarTitle("Home")
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: Works great! Just a note for others: the `.navigationViewStyle` modifier must be attached directly to the `NavigationView`, as shown here. I originally had it attached to my inner view and it did not work.

Comment: Took me a while to find this. Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

That did not work for me nor did using any other NavigationStyle on iPad using IOS 14.2. The root view always looks like this.

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.ideas) { Idea in
                    IdeaListRow(idea: Idea)
                }
                .onDelete { (indexSet) in
                    let ideaToDelete = self.ideas[indexSet.first!]
                    self.managedObjectContext.delete(ideaToDelete)
                    
                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Idea List"))
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    NavigationLink(destination: AddView()) {
                                        Text("Add")
                                    } , trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### ✅ iOS 16

Since the `NavigationView` has been **DEPRECATED** and as Apple suggests:

> Use `NavigationStack` instead. For more information, see [Migrating to new navigation types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack { //  here
            Text("Hello")
                .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### iOS 13

Use `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` modifier on the `NavigationView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello")
                .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack) //  here
    }
}
```