# SwiftUI NavigationView content only visible in iPad sidebar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

My app is working as expected across all iPhone models, but when running on iPad I notice that the my application content, which is wrapped within a `NavigationView`, only displays in the iPad's sidebar, and only after tapping the 'Back` toolbar button.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{

        ...

        }
         .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
         .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Add Light to Your Journey")
                            .font(Font.custom("EduTASBeginner-Regular", size: 24))
                        ...
    }
}
```

I found a similar question on SO that suggested adding the attribute   `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)`, but this did not change the way the app is displayed on iPad:

[image: iPad]

Note the solution on this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624524/navigationview-swiftui-shows-split-view-in-ipad) also did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As noted in the comments on the linked post, the        `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` must be applied directly to the `NavigationView`, and not a view contained therein as with `.navigationTitle`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView`, and it will resolve the issue.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
        ZStack{

    ...

    }
     .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
     .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Add Light to Your Journey")
                        .font(Font.custom("EduTASBeginner-Regular", size: 24))
                    ...
}
```

}